# Why does the LM1881 make an odd/even signal even with progressive inputs?

Tags: analog, video

I noticed that when I apply a 720p or higher signal to an LM1881, the odd/even pin outputs a square wave signal which it shouldn't. On 240p it doesn't, as expected.

Did I miss something? My input is 100% 720p not 720i.

Comment: Maybe it only limited to 480i (NTSC/PAL) since i found the LMH1980

Comment: It says right in [the datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1881.pdf) that it's for NTSC, PAL, and SECAM. 720p is not valid in any of those standards, to the extent of my knowledge.

Comment: @Hearth It says right in the datasheet it supports non-standard formats up to 150 kHz HSYNC rate, so definitely not limited to interlaced SD formats. The external timing components may need adjustment as per the used standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have used standard external timing components which only provide SD video compatibility. The chip itself can go up to 150 kHz horizontal rate, which is not the problem, but different video formats need different external timing components.

The SD video signals have a line period of about 64 us and serration pulses happen at 32 us rate.

If you used the standard 680 kohm Rset resistor, the chip will work with SD rates as 32 us is below threshold and 64 us is above threshold. Which also causes that the chip considers the 22 us line period pulses of 720p signal as the serration pulses instead of hsync line pulses.

That explains the field output toggling, and is expected when 720p is sent to circuit while timing components are set to expect 15.6 kHz SD resolutions.

The Rset should be set to around 250 kHz in case of 720p, to make the chip consider 22 us as standard line rate (and thus 11us serration pulses which won't happen).

Comment: Good to know. Thank you. My plan was to use it with resolution from 240p to 1080p. After reading about the LMH1980, it seems to be the better choice then the LM1881

Comment: Well that’s true.

Answer (score 0):

I’m surprised the LM1881 works at all on 720p - it’s not designed for that, only for SD video and related standards that use low-going sync.

The LMH1980 can support HD and PC standards, including 720p that use tri-level sync. More here: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla097a/snla097a.pdf

Comment: I got it even running at 1080i. I choose it because it was used in a product that supported to 1080i. I guess I need to switch. Luckily i was in the prototyping stage, when I figured it out.

Comment: How is this a correct answer? It says right in the datasheet it supports non-standard formats up to 150 kHz HSYNC rate, so definitely not limited to interlaced SD formats. The external timing components may need adjustment as per the used standard.

Comment: @Justme  Yes, the LM1881 was long the go-to even for VGA capture, before integrated solutions came available. This predates HD (including 720p) by some years. I suppose the sync detect still works with HD tri-level sync since there is still the low-going portion of the waveform. That's a separate issue from h-rate. I added that.